How can I enhance the time complexity of arranging bricks into stacks based on specific conditions?
I’m working on a problem where I need to arrange N bricks of varying lengths into the least number of stacks. The rules for stacking bricks are that a brick
 can be placed on top of brick
 only if the condition

+
 ≤  holds true, where
 is a given integer.
Here is my current implementation in Python:
def arrange_bricks(N, x, bricks):
    # Sort the bricks in descending order
    bricks.sort(reverse=True)

    # List to hold stacks
    stacks = []

    for brick in bricks:
        placed = False
        for stack in stacks:
            if brick + x <= stack[-1]:
                stack.append(brick)
                placed = True
                break
        
        if not placed:
            stacks.append([brick])

    print(len(stacks))
    for stack in stacks:
        print(len(stack), ' '.join(map(str, stack)))

N, x = map(int, input().split())
bricks = list(map(int, input().split()))
arrange_bricks(N, x, bricks)

Problem:
Time Complexity: Currently, the time complexity of my solution is
(^2) in the worst case, as each brick potentially checks against all existing stacks. This can be inefficient, especially when
 is large (up to 10^6).
Desired Outcome: I want to enhance the time complexity to be more efficient, preferably around (log)if possible.
Constraints:
• 1 ≤  ≤ 10^6
• 1 ≤  ≤ 10^9
• 1 ≤  ≤ 10^9
Questions:
How can I modify my approach to use a more efficient data structure or algorithm to reduce the time complexity?
Are there specific algorithms or techniques I can apply to solve this problem more effectively?
Thank you for your help!

This looks like a bin packing problem to me, with some additional constraints. I suspect that finding the optimal solution will be more complex than O(n^2). See the Wikipedia article for info about ways to find an approximate solution.

Is this online somewhere where we can test solutions ourselves?

@JimMischel The stacks here don't have a capacity limit. And the constraints do look like something better than O(n^2) is possible.

@JimMischel You're implying that their code doesn't always find optimal solutions. Can you provide an example case where it doesn't?

@nocomment I don't know if your code finds the optimal solution. The description sounds like it's exponential time problem, so I assumed that your n^2 solution isn't optimum. I could be wrong.

@JimMischel I don't have an n^2 solution. I think I have a nlogn solution, though :-) (with O(n) after the sorting).

@nocomment Then apparently I was wrong. I would be interested in seeing it. And I apologize for my mistake in my previous comment where I implied that you were the OP.

You can optimize your solution to O(N) after the initial sorting of the bricks (so it's O(N log N) overall).
Instead of trying the current brick on all stacks, try just the one with the longest top brick. Keep the stacks sorted by top brick, from longest top brick to shortest top brick. This way you just try the first stack. If you do place the current brick onto it, then that stack now has the shortest top brick, so move that stack to the end.
So import deque from collections and change your
    # List to hold stacks
    stacks = []

    for brick in bricks:
        placed = False
        for stack in stacks:
            if brick + x <= stack[-1]:
                stack.append(brick)
                placed = True
                break
        
        if not placed:
            stacks.append([brick])

to this:
    # Deque to hold stacks
    stacks = deque()

    for brick in bricks:
        if stacks and brick + x <= stacks[0][-1]:
            stacks[0].append(brick)
            stacks.rotate(-1)
        else:
            stacks.append([brick])

Attempt This Online!

That's an interesting solution. Thanks.

@JimMischel Yeah I quite like it. Particularly the use of rotate. Rarely used. I first had stacks.append(stacks.popleft()) until I realized there's a method for that.

A simple greedy algorithm does the trick.
First, sort the bricks into descending order, a1 >= a2 >= ... >= an.
Observation 1: For a stack, we only need to store the length of the top brick.
We'll put the bricks one by one and maintain the sorted length of the top brick of the current stacks in a BST S. For each brick ai, we find the shortest top brick in S such that ai can be put on top (si >= ai + x) if such a top brick exists and put ai on top. Otherwise, we need to start a new stack and put ai as the base brick. Searching the shortest top brick such that ai can be put on top can be done via binary search on the BST S.
Observation 2: This is optimal. It can be proven by the exchange argument.
The outline of the exchange argument goes as follows:
Assume an optimal solution uses n stacks T = {stack_1, stack_2, ..., stack_n} and our algorithm uses m stacks S = {stack_1, stack_2, ..., stack_m}.
We identify the location of a1 in T, say stack_i. a1 must be at the bottom of stack_i.
Now, if a2 + x <= a1 but a2 is not on top of a1 in T, a2 must be at the base of another stack stack_j where i != j. We can swap {stack_i minus a_1} with {stack_j} and the resulted set T' will also be a valid solution with n stacks where the first step of putting a2 matches with our algorithm. We repeat the exchange process recursively by ignoring a1 from T and focuses on {a2, ..., an}
Otherwise, if a2 + x > a1, then a2 must be at the bottom of some stack_j such that i != j. This matches with our algorithm. We repeat the exchange process recursively by ignoring a1 from T and focuses on {a2, ..., an}.
At the very end, the set T will be transformed to S while keeping the number of stacks unchanged, proving that |S| = |T|.

Try making it simpler and faster.

@no This is O(n log n). Do you mean there is an O(n) solution?

Why not pick the longest rather than shortest possible top-of-stack?

@Y.T. Like I said previously, we can do O(n) after the sorting (so still O(n log n) overall). Plus it's simpler.

@גלעדברקן say you have two top-of-stack 1000 and 10000, and you want to put a brick of length 100 on top. Putting it on top of 1000 leaves you with 100 and 10000. Putting it on top of 10000 leaves you with 100 and 1000. Clearly, putting it on the shortest possible top-of-stack gives a better solution.

@Y.T. Why do you think leaving 100 and 10000 is better?

Can you please provide a small example where placing on the largest results in a larger number of stacks?

@גלעדברקן right I think it doesn't really matter in which stack to choose as long as it satisfies the requirements upon further thought as the following brick will have a shorter length anyway. This should allow for a two-pointer solution which is also the solution for no I suppose.

Yes, something like two-pointer. Though I did it differently because they want to print the whole stacks. Which btw makes your Observation 1 wrong, I think (how are you going to print the whole stacks if you only have the top bricks?). Btw your answer is phrased strangely, as if the OP didn't use the same algorithm already, just without your optimization. I'd say better start like "We can improve your algorithm by ...". That helps the reader understand, and acknowledges the OP's work instead of pretending it's not there (which comes across badly).

@Y.T. the next brick might not be shorter. It could be the same. I’m not sure myself if there’s a counter example. I was asking sincerely.

@גלעדברקן I stressed-tested it. Both versions of the program returns the same result. I have convinced myself that choosing the longest available stack will also work. We can also argue both program are equivalent by the exchange argument.

@גלעדברקן There's no counter-example. If this 100 fits on the 1000, then any later 100 would also fit. Or put differently: for the remaining bricks, which are all not longer than 100, there's no difference between the 1000 and the 10000. So it doesn't matter which one you use now.

@Y.T. I can guess that "BST" means binary search tree, but better spell that out. Or better yet, switch to the largest-top approach and don't use a BST :-)
